# How to build a multi bar/ multi line chart with graphic library in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build a bar line chart in flutter using the graphic library, but none of the examples showed how to build a mult bar chart, let alone a bar line.
Here is my attempt at making it.

```
class GraphicChart extends StatefulWidget {
  const GraphicChart(
      {super.key,
      required this.controlName,
      required this.controller,
      required this.chartType});

  final String controlName;
  final ChartController controller;
  final String chartType;

  @override
  State<GraphicChart> createState() => _GraphicChartState();
}

class _GraphicChartState extends State<GraphicChart> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return graphic.Chart(
      data: widget.controller.data,
      variables: {
        "Series": graphic.Variable(
            accessor: (Map map) => map["SeriesName"] as String),
        "2012": graphic.Variable(
            accessor: (Map map) => map["Data"]["2012"] as double),
        "2013": graphic.Variable(
            accessor: (Map map) => map["Data"]["2013"] as double),
        "2014": graphic.Variable(
            accessor: (Map map) => map["Data"]["2014"] as double)
      },
      marks: [
        graphic.IntervalMark(
            position: Varset("Series") * Varset("2012"),
            label: graphic.LabelEncode(
              encoder: (p0) => Label("2012"),
            )),
        graphic.IntervalMark(
            position: Varset("Series") * Varset("2013"),
            label: graphic.LabelEncode(
              encoder: (p0) => Label("2013"),
            )),
        graphic.IntervalMark(
            position: Varset("Series") * Varset("2014"),
            label: graphic.LabelEncode(
              encoder: (p0) => Label("2014"),
            )),
        // graphic.IntervalMark(
        //   position: Varset("Data1") * Varset("Data2") * Varset("Data3"),
        // )
      ],
      axes: [Defaults.verticalAxis, Defaults.horizontalAxis],
    );
  }
}
```

And here is how it looks like:
[image]

As you can see, the bars stacked on top of one another but i wanted it to group together.
Any help would be appreciated.